# JWplayer image fallback, if no html5 or flash support?

Tags: flash, html, html5-video, jwplayer

I'm using JWPlayer to serve an html5 video with a flash fallback.

I'd also like to have an image fallback if there is neither html5 nor flash support but I can't see how to do this.

My code is as follows:

```
modes:  [
   { type: "html5", },
   { type: "flash", src="http://www.mysite.com/jwplayer/player.swf"}
],

levels: [
   { file: "myvideo.mp4" }, // H.264 version
   { file: "myvideo.webm" }, // WebM version
   { file: "myvideo.ogg" } // Ogg Theroa version
],
```

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two utils functions you can use to check for HTML5 and Flash. You can find them here in the [source](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/trunk/js/src/utils/jwplayer.utils.js?rev=1311) (copy & paste the url: http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/trunk/js/src/utils/jwplayer.utils.js?rev=1311):

```
/**
 * Detects whether the browser can handle HTML5 video. 
 * Using this as a proxy for detecting all HTML5 features needed for the JW HTML5 Player.  Do we need more granularity?
 */
jwplayer.utils.hasHTML5 = function() {
    return !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
};

/**
 * Detects whether or not the current player has flash capabilities
 * TODO: Add minimum flash version constraint: 9.0.115
 */
jwplayer.utils.hasFlash = function() {
    return (typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash'] != "undefined") || (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined");
};
```